# Buttons on form not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, button

So I'd like to start by saying this is my first time dealing with JS and I am working on a project for my class.

I have to create a form with three buttons, one that will store the form data, one that will display it and one that will clear the form.  I have been researching to all ends to try and figure out what I am doing wrong.  This is an online class so not much info is given other than here's the book and here's your assignment.

Here's what I have so far, any ideas as to why my store and display buttons are not working and also is there a way I can check to see if the store button is correctly storing the data in arrays and it's just the display button not working?!

I'm ripping my hair out, sorry for being terrible.

```html
<DOCTYPE HTML!>

<html>
<head>
<style>

form {border-style: inset;
 border-color: blue;
 height: 360px;
 width: 775px;
 margin: auto;
 }
 
</style>

<script>

var fullNames = new Array(100);
var dates = new Array(100);
var opinions = new Array(100);

var numOfRatings = 0;

function validateData()
{
 var fullNameStr = document.getElementById("FullName").value;
 var dateStr = document.getElementById("Date").value;
 var opinionStr = document.getElementById("opinion").value;
 {
  var dateVal = dateStr;
  var dateParts = dateVal.split("/");
  if (parseInt(dateParts[2]) < "2014")
   {
   alert("Invalid date!");
   }
  else
  {
   fullNames[numOfRatings] = fullNameStr;
   dates[numOfRatings] = dateStr;
   opinions[numOfRatings] = opinionStr;
   numOfRatings++;
   document.getElementById("FullName").value = "";
   document.getElementById("Date").value = "";
   document.getElementById("opinion").value = "";
  }
 }
}   

function displayData()
{
 var col;
 var pos;
 
 document.getElementById("list").value = "FULL NAME               DATE            RATING\n";
 
 for (pos = 0; pos < numOfRatings; pos++)
 {
  document.getElementById("list").value += fullNames[pos];
  for (col = fullNames[pos].length; col <= 25; col++)
   document.getElementById("list").value += " ";
  document.getElementById("list").value += dates[pos];
  for (col = dates[pos].length; col <= 15; col++)
   document.getElementById("list").value += " ";
  document.getElementById("list").value += opinions[pos]"\n";
 }
}

//Clear data function
function clearData()
{
 var pos;
 
 for (pos = 0; pos < numOfRatings; pos++)
 {
  fullNames[pos] = "";
  dates[pos] = "";
  opinions[pos] = "";
 }
 numOfRatings = 0;
} 

</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<font size="10px"><h1>Internet Technologies Membership</font>
</center>
<b><hr></hr></b>
</h1>
<form name ="ratingForm">
<table cellpadding="10">
<td>
<tr>
<td>Full Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" id="FullName" name="FullName"></td>
<td>Date:</td>
<td><input type="date" id="Date" name="Date"></td>
<td>Opinion:</td>
<td><select name="opinion" id="opinion">
 <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
 <option value="verygood">Very Good</option>
 <option value="good">Good</option>
 <option value="fair">Fair</option>
 <option value="poor">Poor</option>
 <option value="verybad">Very Bad</option>
</select></td>
</table>
<br>
<center>
<td><textarea name="list" id="list" rows="10" cols="100">
</textarea>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="RATE" onClick="validateData();">
<input type="button" value="DISPLAY" onClick="displayData();">
<input type="reset" value="CLEAR" onClick="clearData();">
<br>
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your doctype is written incorrectly, it's supposed to be `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: I had it correct in my actual code, messed up copying it over lol.  Been looking at this wayyy too long today, thank you though!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can modify `displayData()` to this:

```
function displayData() {
            var col;
            var pos;
            var listElement = document.getElementById("list");

            listElement.value = "FULL NAME               DATE            RATING\n";
            for (pos = 0; pos < numOfRatings; pos++) {
                listElement.value += fullNames[pos] + " ".repeat(24 - fullNames[pos].length);
                listElement.value += dates[pos] + " ".repeat(16 - dates[pos].length);
                listElement.value += opinions[pos] + "\n";
            }
        }
```

1. The `repeat()` function is added in ES2015.
2. Find element one time.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is incorrect for this line
    `document.getElementById("list").value += opinions[pos]"\n";`
You forgot the + sign
    `document.getElementById("list").value += opinions[pos]+"\n";`
To look at the JS errors right click on you page, if you're using chrome, and click Inspect Element->Console. It tells you the errors that your page is throwing.

Comment: You have got to be kidding me...LOL that fixed it!

Comment: This single comment has lifted an enormous weight off my shoulders hahaha! Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 0):

You had many errors:

You had an invalid doc type. Your HTML was broken around the H1 Tag. The form tag wasn't closed.

You validation needed clean up in the rate function.

You where missing a + in the display function.

Here is full working code with comments on the fixes and how to go about debugging yourself in the future.

```css
form {
  border-style: inset;
  border-color: blue;
  height: 360px;
  width: 775px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
broken html. 
Use a tool to validate your html and make it "pretty" or "tidy" for you.
-->
<h1 style="text-align:center; border-bottom:1px solid #999999">Internet Technologies Membership</h1>
<!-- 
An HTML validator would have told you <font> and <center> are depcrecated. Replaced with css.
-->
<form name="ratingForm">
  <table cellpadding="10">
    <td>
      <tr>
        <td>Full Name:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="FullName" name="FullName">
        </td>
        <td>Date:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="date" id="Date" name="Date">
        </td>
        <td>Opinion:</td>
        <td>
          <select name="opinion" id="opinion">
            <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
            <option value="verygood">Very Good</option>
            <option value="good">Good</option>
            <option value="fair">Fair</option>
            <option value="poor">Poor</option>
            <option value="verybad">Very Bad</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <center>
    <td>
      <textarea name="list" id="list" rows="10" cols="100">
      </textarea>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="RATE" onclick="validateData();">
      <input type="button" value="DISPLAY" onclick="displayData();">
      <input type="reset" value="CLEAR" onclick="clearData();">
      <br>
  </center>
 <!-- add missing end form tag -->
</form>
<!-- when javascript isn't working, put different blocks inside of seperate script tags.
If there is an error in one everything inside the script tag wont work.
Using seperate script tags you find out which block of code isn't working.
Also, look in web developer console for errors in the console tab.

-->
<script>
var fullNames = new Array(100);
var dates = new Array(100);
var opinions = new Array(100);

var numOfRatings = 0;
</script>
<!-- put validateData() in its own script tag to isolate it because it wasn't working. -->
<script>

function validateData() {
  //console.log('validating data'); // use console.log to see what code is executing
  var fullNameStr = document.getElementById("FullName").value;
  var dateStr = document.getElementById("Date").value;
  var opinionStr = document.getElementById("opinion").value;
  //console.log('validating data 1'); // making sure the getters didn't break anything.
  // add validation for name and opinion. 
  //If they are null then display won't work because a string + null==null;
  if(!fullNameStr||!opinionStr|| !dateStr) {
   alert("Please complete all fields.");
    return;
  }
  var dateVal = dateStr;
  var dateParts = dateVal.split("/");
  
  // need to validate the dataParts array has at least two items.
  // also SHOULD be making sure it is a validate date.
  if (dateParts.length<3 || parseInt(dateParts[2]) < "2014") {
    alert("Invalid date!");
  } else {
    fullNames[numOfRatings] = fullNameStr;
    dates[numOfRatings] = dateStr;
    opinions[numOfRatings] = opinionStr;
    numOfRatings++;
    document.getElementById("FullName").value = "";
    document.getElementById("Date").value = "";
    document.getElementById("opinion").value = "";
  }
}
</script>

<!-- put displayData() in its own script tag to isolate it because it wasn't working. -->
<script>

function displayData() {
  var col;
  var pos;

  document.getElementById("list").value = "FULL NAME               DATE            RATING\n";

  for (pos = 0; pos < numOfRatings; pos++) {
    document.getElementById("list").value += fullNames[pos];
    for (col = fullNames[pos].length; col <= 25; col++)
      document.getElementById("list").value += " ";
    document.getElementById("list").value += dates[pos];
    for (col = dates[pos].length; col <= 15; col++)
      document.getElementById("list").value += " ";
      //broken code, add + after opinions[pos]
    document.getElementById("list").value += opinions[pos] +   "\n";
  }
}
</script>

<!-- put clearData() in its own script tag to isolate it because it wasn't working. -->
<script>

//Clear data function
function clearData() {
  var pos;

  for (pos = 0; pos < numOfRatings; pos++) {
    fullNames[pos] = "";
    dates[pos] = "";
    opinions[pos] = "";
  }
  numOfRatings = 0;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  The info you provided me is very helpful and I will definitely use better HTML formatting in the future. I am very new to JS so I apologize for the eye sore!

Comment: I wanted to mention that when I run your code, no matter what date I enter it is coming back as invalid!  The assignment actually states that it must reject the date if it is less than 2014 or greater than the current date.

Comment: `1/1/2014` works for me. Using firefox latest. You? Check into using the Web developer console and debugger and try stepping through the code.